# VBA code - Group by matching columns using SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Input:

```
G   F   V   S   P   M
10  1   1   1   1   a
10  1   1   1   1   b
10  1   2   1   1   c
10  2   1   1   1   c
11  1   1   1   1   d
11  1   1   2   1   d
11  1   1   2   1   e
```

Output should be:

```
G   F   V   S   P   M
10  1   1   1   1   a, b
10  1   2   1   1   c
10  2   1   1   1   c
11  1   1   1   1   d, e
11  1   1   2   1   d, e
```

```
Public Function Test()

Dim sqlCON As New ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlREC As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlSTR As String
Dim sqlSTR2 As String
Dim newWB As Workbook

Set newWB = ActiveWorkbook

With sqlCON
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & newWB.FullName & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

sqlSTR = "SELECT G, F, V, S, P, M " & _
          "FROM [Sheet1$];"

Set sqlREC = sqlCON.Execute(sqlSTR)
If sqlREC.BOF = False And sqlREC.EOF = False Then
    getAD = sqlREC.GetRows
Else
    getAD = Empty
End If
Set sqlREC = Nothing

sqlCON.Close
```

In the SELECT section of the code, I have already tried FOR XML PATH, STRING_AGG and GROUP_CONCAT, but had no success, it seems these functions are not supported in VBA.

The "ID" of the row is a combination of all the columns, where the leading column is V, for each V (combined with the other columns) we have a combination of M.

Does someone have a clue on how I can get the desired output?

Comment: To be precise, it's not VBA that doesn't support the db functions but rather the data provider engine that you're using.  You are using the MS Access engine with that connection string which, as you correctly point out, does not support those functions.  They are supported by MS SQL Server.

Comment: @squillman good observation, thank you. Do you know if there is a similar function in MS Access engine? Or if there is a list of all the functions available for this engine?

Comment: Your images don't show for me at work, can you elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of similar functionality; I don't do much with that provider.  Here is the Access 2013 SQL reference.  I'm not finding the one for Access 2010 which is what you're referencing.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have changed the images to a list.